# Unintended SQL Server 2008 Express instance installed

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I installed `SQL Server 2008 R2 Expess` with an instance name `SQLX08`, then I installed `SQL Server 2012 Expess` with an instance name `SQLX12`.
Now in the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` I see, along with these 2 instances, another instance named `SQLEXPRESS` is running which I didn't install. It's version shows 10.0.5500.0. That means it's an `SQL Server 2008` instance, not an `R2` one.
When I open the `2008 R2 SSMSE`, this `SQLEXPRESS` instance doesn't show up in the `Server Name` dropdown list, but it does in the `2012 SSMSE`.

Can anyone tell how, when and why this instance got installed?

Comment: Typically this gets installed with certain applications. Review the list of stuff you have installed.

Comment: Did you install VS 2010? VS 2010 installs SQL 2008 Express